# Flutter: Align items in a row vertically

Tags: flutter

I have a Row which has a Text and a Checkbox, how can I align the Checkbox so they are all aligned vertically?

```dart
Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Some",
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )),
            Checkbox(
              checkColor: Colors.white,
              fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(getColor),
              value: isChecked,
              onChanged: (bool? value) {
                setState(() {
                  isChecked = value!;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Some other very long name",
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )),
            Checkbox(
              checkColor: Colors.white,
              fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(getColor),
              value: isSecondChecked,
              onChanged: (bool? value) {
                setState(() {
                  isSecondChecked = value!;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

[image]

Comment: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // place this
        children: [

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for, but it gives me an idea on how to work with it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Table layout
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html

Comment: seems like you cannot scroll tables.

Comment: First, I paste your code and the the result is aligned you may miss some of the code above that control column width anyway, to align it vertically you have to wap your text with container and set width to the container in both of the rows now the check box will be at the same line and the text also,you can use text overflow elipses when text width pass container width

Answer (score 0):

Add `Spacer` widget with `flex:1` between widgets in row

```
const Spacer(
   flex: 1,
),
```

on the whole

```
              Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                          child: Text(
                            "Some",
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          )),
                      const Spacer(
                        flex: 1,
                      ),
                      Checkbox(
                        checkColor: Colors.white,
                        value: true,
                        onChanged: (bool? value) {},
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                          child: Text(
                            "Some other very long name",
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          )),
                      const Spacer(
                        flex: 1,
                      ),
                      Checkbox(
                        value: true,
                        checkColor: Colors.white,
                        onChanged: (bool? value) {},
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              )
```

Output is :

[image: here is what u needed]

Answer (score 0):

[For more info about row and column refer to this link](https://medium.com/jlouage/flutter-row-column-cheat-sheet-78c38d242041)

Result:

[image]

Please refer to below code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ChatSampleWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChatSampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChatSampleWidgetState createState() => _ChatSampleWidgetState();
}

class _ChatSampleWidgetState extends State<ChatSampleWidget> {
  bool isSecondChecked = false;
  bool isChecked = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Chatter'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Some",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  )),
              Checkbox(
                checkColor: Colors.white,
                value: isChecked,
                onChanged: (bool? value) {
                  setState(() {
                    isChecked = value!;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Some other very long name",
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              Checkbox(
                checkColor: Colors.white,
                value: isSecondChecked,
                onChanged: (bool? value) {
                  setState(
                    () {
                      isSecondChecked = value!;
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to create two columns in a row, and align then for instance 80:20 like you would do with a flexbox, and then within the columns align let's say left and middle. I am just trying to learn that is why I have these examples.

Comment: Yes, we can do that you can either use flex property in Row or you can use sized box with MediaQuery to occupy 80% of screen width and other SizedBox with 20%

Answer (score 0):

```
Column(
      children: [
        Row(
              mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,

          children: [
            const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Some",
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )),
            Checkbox(
              checkColor: Colors.white,
              fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(getColor),
              value: isChecked,
              onChanged: (bool? value) {
                setState(() {
                  isChecked = value!;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(                  
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,

          children: [
            const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Some other very long name",
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )),
            Checkbox(
              checkColor: Colors.white,
              fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(getColor),
              value: isSecondChecked,
              onChanged: (bool? value) {
                setState(() {
                  isSecondChecked = value!;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```